# Wrong Macintosh HD icon after Catalina Upgrade

Tags: catalina

After upgrading to Catalina 10.15.2 the Macintosh HD icon on my Desktop and other places is showing what looks like a Chrome disk image icon instead. I've tried restarting and running first aid on the volume with no changes. Any ideas how to restore the normal icon?

[image: desktop icon]

[image: disk utility icon]

Comment: I'd try the following: Select the **Macintosh HD** icon on the **Desktop** and then press **⌘I** to bring up its **Get Info** _sheet_, or _right-click_ and select **Get Info**. Then click the _icon_ in the upper left corner of its **Get Info** _sheet_ to select it. Now press the **Delete** _key_.  What hopefully happens is the icon for **Google Chrome** is deleted and the default icon reappears.

Comment: If that doesn't work, try the following: In **Terminal** use the `open /System/Library/Extensions/IOStorageFamily.kext/Contents/Resources` _command_ to open **Finder** to that location. Open the **Internal.icns** in **Preview**, and press **⌘A** then  **⌘C** to copy all images to the **Clipboard**. Now in the **Get Info** _sheet_ for the **Macintosh HD** icon select the icon in the upper left corner and press  **⌘V** to paste the icons. While technically not back to normal, nonetheless you should now have the correct icon showing for the  **Macintosh HD**.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions but unfortunately neither of those seemed to work. Deleting the icon from the info screen seems like a common solution, I'm not sure why it isn't working for me.

Comment: Using the Internal.icns trick did work for me. My problem the first time was I was selecting the versions of the icon in the sidebar that Preview displays and not the main version. Using the File -> Edit menu to select everything worked though!

Comment: @user3439894 The `delete` or `⌘ + delete` does not work in the `Get Info` UI for removing icons unfortunately. That was the 1st answer I found when searching to fix the problem.

Comment: @Terry Wang, If a copy of an _image_ has been pasted into the _icon_ on a _files/folders_ **Get Info** _window_, **then it can indeed be deleted!** I've done it many times.

Comment: @user3439894 I've done that before as well (I remember doing it a couple of times for older version of macOS). I was expecting the same would work for removing the Chrome icon but it didn't. I think it's still related how this icon got stuck onto to the Macintosh HD in the first place lol

Answer (score 4):

None of the workarounds mentioned in comments worked for me, so I decided to write a separate answer for people with the same trouble.

Experienced the same issue since the upgrade from Mojave 10.14 to Catalina (10.15.1), felt unreal and confused. Spent 10-15 mins searching and troubleshooting trying to fix but no luck (including Get Info - Upper Left corner - select the Icon - `⌘ + delete` - it didn't work).

Mysterious and no one can explain how and why it happened (if you can, please_).

`Disk Utility.app` show the same Chrome Disk Image icon, didn't find a way to force a refresh or delete it.

[image: Disk Utility.app]

I was hoping that the issue would be fixed by macOS patches but obviously `NO` up until `10.15.4`, that's why I ended up here lol.

So the solution that worked for me:

1. In Terminal (or `iTerm2`)

```bsh
open /System/Library/Extensions/IOStorageFamily.kext/Contents/Resources
```

2. Open `internal.icns` in `Preview.app`
3. Select all icons included by using `⌘ + A` and copy to clipboard `⌘ + C`
4. In `Get Info` UI, click on the upper left corner icon to select it
5. Paste `⌘ + V`, if this does NOT work, use the file menu - `Edit - Paste`, 
   the latter worked like a charm for me, finally...

> NOTE: In my case, I didn't select all icons included in the icon resource file, so the paste ended up with a wrong one, when I use the file menu - `Edit - Undo`, it just refreshed to the correct Icon, hmm... Anyway, it worked. Thanks to @user3439894 and OP @jjathman

Comment: Like others, I couldn't select the icon in Get Info.  Also, the paste from internal.icns didn't work, but then hitting Undo after that did restore the original.

Comment: @EthanDuckworth Can't believe it's still hitting people. Glad to see it fixed the annoying problem for you.

Comment: @EthanDuckworth I could select the icon but could not paste (perhaps, as mentioned in a comment on the OP, I selected all icons in the sidebar, not "select all" from a single icon. But like you, I noticed that there was an "undo paste" option in the edit menu, which did the trick. I would recommend that anyone who has this problem go to the "Get Info" window and see if there is a paste to undo...